# What is the best way to evaluate user inputed comparison string against a object?

Tags: c#, reflection

If I have a user give a string such as

`eval= "productId = '100' and (GUID = '100' or (GUID = '200' and productId = '100' ) )"`

what would be the best way to use the string to see if a object in memory meets those constraints? For example the following model would evaluate true:

`evaluate(eval, new Product{productId ='100', GUID='100'})`

Anyone push me in the direction of a design pattern that could accomplish this?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+parse+evaluate

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  *What is the best....* questions are usually not well received since they inherently ask for an opinion.

Comment: taking a step back, why is the user being invited to send information in such a format? Is there not a more structured way to receive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/) and reflection, an *Evaluate* method can be written like:

```
public object Evaluate(string exprString, object o)
{
    var dict = o.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p);

    var expr = new NCalc.Expression(exprString);
    expr.EvaluateParameter += (name, e) =>
    {
        e.Result = dict[name].GetValue(o, null);
    };

    return expr.Evaluate();

}
```

---

```
var res = Evaluate(
             "productId = '100' and (GUID = '100' or (GUID = '200' and productId = '100' ) )", 
             new { productId = "100", GUID = "100" });
```

---

OR

```
var res2 = Evaluate("x + 100 + y", new { x = 10, y = 1 });
```

---

*PS: Error checks + "public fields" of the given object are ignored for simplicity*

Comment: Wow, this is powerful. Works perfectly. Thanks!